# Sort Array by Value Date with Different Key / ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-native

I have a complexe usecase.
Basically I got this array :

```
   Array [
       a {
            value : "false"
            creation : date
         }
       b {
            value : "false"
            creation : date
         }
       c {
            value : "false"
            infos : {
                     new_creation : date
                       ...
                    }
         }  
       d {
            value : "false"
            infos : {
                       new_creation : date
                       ...
                    }
         }
]
```

And so I want to sort it by date, but as you can see the key are not all the same, and the organization too... 
I watched may function to try it like all the stuff around the `sort(), map(),...` but because the key are different and the structure too, it was difficult...
Any ideas ? Thanks for your help ! USING React-JS/React Native

Comment: I would suggest to convert it to a normal array of object with the same key value then sort it

Comment: so new creation is newer ? I suggest spiting them to two array of with and withouth creation at parent level then depending on your use case maybe try adding your second array back the first one

Comment: I thought about that, but even if I change the key, I still have the problem with the structure of the array to sort it... No ?

Comment: yeah Ash basically it s a concatenation of two array, they are separately  sorted, but potentially, when I concat them, some elements could be younger (dates) than some from the other array..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the following factors. 
1) The date is Javascript Date Object
2) The depth difference will only be one
3) The changed key will known to you prior itself and its wont change
Here is code: Its self Explanatory

```
    arr = [
    {creation:new Date()},
    {creation:new Date("9/21/2009")},
    {infos: {
        new_creation:new Date("9/22/2009")
    }
}
]
arr.sort(function(a,b){
```

return (a.creation!=undefined?a.creation.getTime():a.infos.new_creation.getTime()) > (b.creation!=undefined?b.creation.getTime():b.infos.new_creation.getTime())
    })